# Add the numbers inside the list repeatedly?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I want to continuously add each element in the array based on the number of items the inner loop iterates. If the input size is 3 the outer loop will also iterate 3x, and for every iteration the inner loop also iterates 3x for a total of 9x. What I'm trying to figure out how will I continuously and repeatedly add all the items inside the array for 9x going back and fourth to the elements?

```
int sum = 0;
int arr[] = {1, 5, 0, 5, 5};
int size = 3;  

for(location = 0; location < size; location++)
{
    for(location3 = 0; location3 < size; location3++)
    {
        sum = sum + arr[location3];
        printf("%d %d %d\n", location+1, location3, sum);
    }
}
```

Since the above code has an input size of 3, the outer loop iterates 3 times and for every iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop iterates 3x. It only adds the first 3 elements in the array and goes back at the beginning. What I wanted is to add all the items (E.g. 1+5+0+5+5 and repeat sum + 1+5+0+5 for a total of 9 times) in the array continuously for 9x since it is the total iteration. Any help? This is my expected output:

```
1  0  1
1  1  6
1  2  6
2  0  11
2  1  16
2  2  17
3  0  22
3  1  22
3  2  27
```

Comment: I don't quite understand your explanation. What's the expected outcome for your sample data?

Comment: If you squint when you look at this problem, you can see FizzBuzz. You're even using the same values, i.e. 3 and 5.

Answer (score 2):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int sum = 0;
    int arr[] = { 1, 5, 0, 5, 5 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( arr ) / sizeof( *arr );

    size_t size = 3;  

    for ( size_t location = 0; location < size; location++ )
    {
        for ( size_t location3 = 0; location3 < size; location3++ )
        {
            sum = sum + arr[( location3 + location * size ) % N];
            printf( "%zu %zu %d\n", location+1, location3, sum );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1 0 1
1 1 6
1 2 6
2 0 11
2 1 16
2 2 17
3 0 22
3 1 22
3 2 27
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is an extra variable that will iterate the elements of array and which initialized when reach the array limit.

```
int sum = 0;
int arr[] = {1, 5, 0, 5, 5};
int size = 3;  
int location, location3;
int elem = 0; //iterate array elements

for(location = 0; location < size; location++)
{
    for(location3 = 0; location3 < size; location3++)
    {
        sum = sum + arr[elem];  // use the extra variable
        printf("%d %d %d\n", location+1, location3, sum);
        elem++;
        if(elem == 5)  //Zero iterator
            elem = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your use of the word *iterate* is confusing here; *count* would work better.